# How I can show the values in the contour lines? clabel not work

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

This is my code:

```
syms x y;
f= x^2/(y-y^2);
ezcontour(f,[-1,1],[0.1,0.9]);
```

How can i show the labels? I wan to show something like this:
[image: ContourLinesExample]

Thank You very much!

Comment: What does "clabel not work" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clabel` wants as an input the contour matrix being displayed by the [Contour object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html). While [`ezcontour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezcontour.html) doesn't return the matrix like [`contour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) does, the Contour object has a [`'ContourMatrix'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html#zmw57dd0e129440). If you specify an output for `ezcontour` it will return the handle to the plotted contour that can be queried directly.

For example:

```
f = @(x, y) x.^2/(y-y.^2);

h = ezcontour(f, [-1, 1], [0.1, 0.9]);
C = h.ContourMatrix;  % R2014b or newer
% C = get(h, 'ContourMatrix');  % R2014a and older
clabel(C, h);
```

Returns the desired output:

[image: yay]

Alternatively, you can can just pass the handle to the contour to obtain the same result:

```
clabel([], h);
```

Per the documentation:

> If you do not have the contour matrix `C`, then replace C with `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `contour`  :

```
x = [-1:0.01:1];
y = [0.1:0.01:0.9];
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
f= X.^2./(Y-Y.^2);
[C, h] = contour(f);
clabel(C, h);
```

[image: contour]

Comment: Owww, really nice and useful answer! Thank you very very much! :)

Comment: I guess he meant it doesn't work with *ez*contour. I wonder if there is a way of using only ezcontour since it does not output the C values....

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Yes, it work very well!, i only have one more question, can i put (0.1 to 0.9) in Y and (-1 to 1) in X?

Comment: No, X and Y are the grid matrices. You should put the respective values in **y** and **x**